# navigate between screens based on if condition result in flutter

Tags: flutter, if-statement, navigation

i have created a button to initiate a method after pressing this button , and this method applying if condition and i need to go to specific screen based on the result of this if statement but every time nothing happens , i don't even get an error!

1- the button:

```
RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('check'),
                  onPressed: _mobilestate,
                )
```

2  the method :

```
  _mobilestate() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => XDdetectingproblems19(),
      );



    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => XDdetectingproblems14(),
      );
    }
  }
```

i added the routes in main. dart as below :

```
  routes: {
        '/XDdetectingproblems19' :(context) => XDdetectingproblems19(),
        '/XDdetectingproblems14' :(context) => XDdetectingproblems14(),

      },
```

Please advise , noting that the button and the method working fine , but the issue is with the navigation step.

Comment: onPressed doesn't consume a widget!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `MaterialPageRoute` in your `_mobileState()` method which doesn't push to any screen. You are meant to be pushing to any desired route.

I added a demo code of how your to help you get what you want done:

```
     RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('check'),
                  onPressed: () async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      // navigate to the desired route
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/XDdetectingproblems19');
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      // navigate to the desired route
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/XDdetectingproblems14');
    }
  },
 )
```

Comment: thanks for your support but when i used the code you mentioned i got the below error :  Compiler message:
lib/XDchooseprpblem6.dart:461:27: Error: The getter 'context' isn't defined for the class 'XDchooseprpblem6'.
 - 'XDchooseprpblem6' is from 'package:new_mit/XDchooseprpblem6.dart' ('lib/XDchooseprpblem6.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/XDdetectingproblems19');
                          ^^^^^^^